# How do I access programmatically created child views in another function

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on a custom sticker application and I'd like to change the background color of the stickerBrowserView during the willTransition function. I've created a child view programmatically which is added during viewDidLoad

```
func createBrowser() {
    let controller = MSStickerBrowserViewController(stickerSize: .regular)

    addChildViewController(controller)

    controller.stickerBrowserView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black

    controller.stickerBrowserView.dataSource = self
}
```

How do I reference this view outside of the createBrowser() function? I'm new to Swift and am still learning. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

can create object and assign to global variable

```
lazy var controller: MSStickerBrowserViewController = {

let controller = MSStickerBrowserViewController(stickerSize: .regular)

// Add View Controller as Child View Controller
self.addChildViewController(controller)

return controller
}()
```

and then used where you need

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks. Is this the best way to go about it?

Comment: Have you experienced this error before? 

    Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <CKPresentationControllerRootViewController: 0x110a34c20>.